# Where is imported DD to WebSphere Portal placed

Tags: java, xml, portlet, websphere-portal

I installed PaymentPortlet.ear app to WebSphere WAS, Then I imported PaymentPortlet.xml to WebSphere Portal, so I could put the portlet on a page.

The question is: Now when I've imported PaymentPortlet.xml to the portal, where can I find it either on portal interface or in the file system?

Actually I don't understand, what happens right after importing the xml

Answer (score 0):

By installing the ear on the WAS console, the portal has no idea that there was anything installed, by importing the xml into the portal you are basically letting the portal know that there was a new ear/war installed and that it contains portlets it can provide.

I find it simpler to install portlet wars by using the portal interface instead of WAS console directly, this way you don't have to register(import xml) the portlets. You can do this by going to Portal Administration -> Portlet Management -> Web Modules -> Install and for update, you find the existing war in the list and update.

Answer (score 0):

The portal runs the xml access once you import the xml. The portal does the operations that you describe in the xml. In this case when you imported the xml the portal registered the portlet from the parameters and the location you described in the xml. Now whenever the portlet is requested it will run the EAR that you deployed on WAS. You can find the registered portlets under Portal administration > Portlets.